# How to increase the porformance of this View/Query?

Tags: mysql, view, query-optimization

I have a Mysql View it runs about 9 seconds. I really need to increase the performance of this view. Here is my Code:

```
SELECT
        `tad`.`TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID` AS `TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID`,
        `lvdu`.`USERNAME` AS `USERNAME`,
        `cdm`.`DOMICILE_LOOK_UP_ID` AS `DOMICILE_LOOK_UP_ID`,
        CAST(
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                DISTINCT `ptlm`.`LOAD_ID` SEPARATOR ','
            ) AS CHAR(255) CHARSET utf8mb4
        ) AS `LOAD_RELATED`,
        MIN(`ptlm`.`PLANNED_START_DATETIME`) AS `PLANNED_START_DATETIME`
    FROM
           `Appian`.`LDA_TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS` `tad`
                LEFT JOIN `Appian`.`LDA_VIEW_DRIVER_AND_USER_DETAILS` `lvdu`
                ON
                    (
                        `tad`.`DRIVER_DETAILS_ID` = `lvdu`.`DRIVER_DETAILS_ID`
                    )                    
            LEFT JOIN `Appian`.`LDA_VIEW_CARRIER_DOMICILE_MAPPING` `cdm`
            ON
                (
                    `lvdu`.`CARRIER_LOOK_UP_ID` = `cdm`.`CARRIER_LOOK_UP_ID`
                )
        LEFT JOIN `Appian`.`LDA_POD_TRIP_LOAD_MAPPING` `ptlm`
        ON
            (
                `tad`.`TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID` = `ptlm`.`TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_ID`
            )
    WHERE
        `tad`.`TRIP_STATUS` IN('Force De-Assigned', 'Completed') AND `tad`.`TRIP_ASSIGNED_TIME` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
    GROUP BY
        `tad`.`TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID`
    ORDER BY
        `tad`.`TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID`
    DESC
```

View **LDA_VIEW_DRIVER_AND_USER_DETAILS (1329 rows)** and **LDA_VIEW_CARRIER_DOMICILE_MAPPING (216 rows)** have pretty good performance and it only takes 0.01 sec. But once I run this query it takes about 9 seconds.

**LDA_TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS: only 19401 rows**

**LDA_POD_TRIP_LOAD_MAPPING: only 11056 rows**

TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID is the primary Key of **LDA_TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS**

***There are no index for LDA_POD_TRIP_LOAD_MAPPING table.***

Please give me some hint for solving this,

I will be much appreciate!!!!

Comment: Please let me know if you need anymore details, thanks!

Comment: Queries against views in MySQL cannot use indexes, so performance is always going to suffer

Comment: As for more details, as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes guesswork to offer definitive advice about optimizing this query. Why?

1. You haven't shown us the  table definitions.
2. You haven't shown us the view definitions, or the definitions of the underlying tables.

The MySQL query planner compiles view definitions into each query and then figures out the best way to satisfy it. [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) for more information about how to put together a good [query-optimizattion](/questions/tagged/query-optimizattion) question.

**All that being said,** these parts of your query jump out at me.

```
SELECT tad.TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID AS TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID,
....
    ON tad.DRIVER_DETAILS_ID = lvdu.DRIVER_DETAILS_ID
...
 WHERE tad.TRIP_STATUS IN('Force De-Assigned', 'Completed')
   AND tad.TRIP_ASSIGNED_TIME > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
...
  ORDER BY tad.TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID DESC
```

If you create a covering index it can optimize your WHERE clause and provide the column data for your SELECT and ON clauses. That may help your query run fast.

This is the index I suggest

```
CREATE INDEX TAD_LOOKUP 
    ON Appian.LDA_TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS 
       (TRIP_STATUS, 
        TRIP_ASSIGNED_TIME, 
        TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID DESC,
        DRIVER_DETAILS_ID);
```

This is [called a *covering index*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) because it contains all columns needed to satisfy your query. `TRIP_STATUS` is first because it shows up as an equality filer in your WHERE clause. `TRIP_ASSIGNED_TIME` is second because it shows up as a range match. That means MySQL can random-access the index to the first relevant row, then scan the index sequentially to get the data you need.

The other two columns are in the index just because your query needs their values, not because they're part of the search.

Another index will probably also help, for simiar reasons.

```
CREATE INDEX PTLM_LOOKUP 
    ON Appian.LDA_POD_TRIP_LOAD_MAPPING
     (PTLM_TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_ID, LOAD_ID);
```

**Pro tip:** It's vitally important that you, and the next person to work on your code, are able to reason about your queries. That means formatting them to be readable is worth every second you spend doing it. Take a look above at how I formatted your WHERE clause, so all filtering predicates appear near the left margin. (I also left out the backticks around names, because they irritate me. But that's just me.)

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by adding a index to LDA_POD_TRIP_LOAD_MAPPING table on TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS_ID , it increasing the speed of left join.